# How to keep column images in responsive email table same height

Tags: html, css

As part of an email template that has to be responsive, (and also unfortunately table-based) I have three columns that have images of identical size in them. The images need to be in separate table cells, as there also needs to be text beneath them.

Unfortunately, if I set the width of the table cells to 33.3% and the images as being 100% of the width of the table cell, I end up with a situation where one of the images is often 1 pixel shorter than the others, at the maximum size of 800 pixels but also at other, smaller browser window sizes.

If I set the img to `min-height:100%` this fixes the height problem, but my design is now no longer responsive.

Here's my CSS...

```
.email_table {
  max-width:800px;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.email_cell {
  width: 33.3%;
}
.email_cell img {
  display: block;  
  width: 100% !important;
  /*min-height:100%;*/
}
```

... and my HTML ...

```
<table class="email_table">
  <tr>
    <td class="email_cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/265x177" >
    </td>
    <td class="email_cell">
<img src="http://placehold.it/265x177" alt="" border="0" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;display: block;width: 100% !important;">        
    </td>
    <td class="email_cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/265x177" >
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Has anyone else come across this problem and found a solution for it?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use tables?, Or you can work with a different approach also ?

Comment: Thanks @NanditaAroraSharma, unfortunately I have to use tables - it's a custom MailChimp template.

Comment: I've updated the question to state that I need a table-based answer.

Comment: ok. I will try it with table structure today. Will post if I find something

Comment: I have added another answer. Please check if it works for you. and let me know if u want to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated/Added these styles

```
tr {
  display: flex;
}
.email_cell {
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
 
.email_table {
  max-width:800px;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
}
.email_cell {
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 0;
}
.email_cell img {
  display: block;  
  width: 100% !important;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="email_table">
  <tr>
<td class="email_cell">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/265x177" >
</td>
<td class="email_cell">
<img src="http://placehold.it/265x177" alt="" border="0" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;display: block;width: 100% !important;">        
</td>
<td class="email_cell">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/265x177" >
</td>    
  </tr>
```

Comment: that works well, thanks! I didn't realise you could use Flexbox inside a table.

Comment: Yes, display : block is far from ideal, but it's the only solution that will make a table responsive, and unfortunately MailChimp templates are meant to be built out of tables. Thanks for making the effort of finding the solution below, and I've marked it as the correct one because it answers the question, but I probably won't be able to use it, because many email clients (including GMail and Outlook.com) don't support Flexbox. I think I have to go back to the drawing board!

Comment: Its not recommened to do this ! But this was the only way I could do what you asked for

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) for your problem. Its responsive and satisfies your criteria(I think).

Also tables are always avoided when you want a responsive web design.

```css
 
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/265x177" >
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/265x177" >
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/265x177" >
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```